# Get background color from the first child of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code :

```
<div id="my-color-picker-1" class="color-picker jcolor-picker"> 
   <div data-type="btn" style="background: rgb(150,78,78)"></div>
</div>
```

I want to get this color : `rgb(150,78,78)`;

I tried like this :

```
let x = document.getElementsByClassName("color-picker").firstChild;
```

But I have an undefined error.

Can you please give me some advices ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByClassName("color-picker")[0]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: What about this one? `document.getElementsByClassName("color-picker").childNodes[0];`

Comment: @GillesHeinesch no, because `getElementsByClassName` doesn't have that property

Comment: Because `getElementsByClassName` returns a "collection", not a single item

Answer (score 2):

**1**

You can also get the background using `children`  property on the node Element also.

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("color-picker");
const background = elements[0].children[0].style.background;
console.log( background );
```

```html
<div id="my-color-picker-1" class="color-picker jcolor-picker"> 
   <div data-type="btn" style="background: rgb(150,78,78)"></div>
</div>
```

**2**

```js
let element = document.getElementsByClassName("color-picker")[0]
const bgColor = element.firstElementChild.style.background;
console.log( bgColor );
```

```html
<div id="my-color-picker-1" class="color-picker jcolor-picker"> 
   <div data-type="btn" style="background: rgb(150,78,78)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**firstChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) will return you the node's first child in the tree.

Then you need [**nextSibling**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) that returns the node immediately following the specified one in their parent's childNodes

```js
let bgColor = document.querySelector("#my-color-picker-1").firstChild.nextSibling.style.backgroundColor

console.log(bgColor);
```

```html
<div id="my-color-picker-1" class="color-picker jcolor-picker">
  <div data-type="btn" style="background: rgb(150,78,78)"></div>
</div>
```